# Сохранение выбора select в Storage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Нужно сохранить выбор `select` в `Storage`. А так же сделать игнорирование сохранения по определенному `name`.

**Код:**

```
var selects = $("#dialog_id select");
for (var key in selects) {
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(key)) && isFinite(key)) {
        var select = selects[key];
        var nameselect = $(select).attr('name');
        $(select).val(localStorage.getItem(nameselect));
    }
}
```

Собственно благодаря нему, в диалоге берутся все `select` и при выборе `option` в нем, данный выбор сохраняется в `Storage`. При следующем открытии такого окна, последний выбор будет стоять по умолчанию.

Так вот, есть такие `select`, на которые подобный функционал не должен распространяться. У этих отдельных `select` есть заданные `name`.

Можно ли как-то их исключить? Буду очень благодарен за совет!

Comment: пусть для примера будет name="ignor"

Comment: в коде нет сохранения в `localStorage`, есть только чтение из него по имени

Comment: console.log('selects:', selects); вы это имеете ввиду? Прошу прощения, я только начал изучение стореджа. ((

Comment: ` $(select).val(localStorage.getItem(nameselect));` Данные брать то, берете, а записывать не записываете.

Comment: в моем случае этого хватило для задумки...отрабатывает и выводит последний выбор. Хотя вы меня сейчас прям в штопор вогнали...

Comment: метод `onChange` на `select` ещё должен быть, ну или тот, кто рулит измененным списком. После выбора надо данные записать в `storage` чтобы их потом использовать. `localStorage.setItem([, params])` у вас нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Набросал код, который сохраняет выбранные данные в селектах по имени.

**Код рабочий. Проверил.**

```
<div id="dialog_id">
    <select name="vlad" onChange="selectChanges(this, value);">
        <option value="1">Value1</option>
        <option value="2">Value2</option>
        <option value="3">Value3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="semen" onChange="selectChanges(this, value);">
        <option value="1">Value1</option>
        <option value="2">Value2</option>
        <option value="3">Value3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="vasya" onChange="selectChanges(this, value);">
        <option value="1">Value1</option>
        <option value="2">Value2</option>
        <option value="3">Value3</option>
    </select>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var selects = $("#dialog_id select");
    for (var key in selects) {
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(key)) && isFinite(key)) {
            var select = selects[key];
            var nameSelect = $(select).attr('name');
            console.log(nameSelect);
            $(select).val(localStorage.getItem(nameSelect));
        }
    }
    function selectChanges(obj, value) {
        var $obj = $(obj);
        var name = $obj.attr('name');

        // дальше код проверки - нужно ли сохранять 
        var notSaveIn = ['массив', 'ненужных', 'элементов'];
        if (notSaveIn.indexOf(name) === -1) {
            localStorage.setItem(name, value)
            console.log(localStorage.getItem(name));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: а если, к примеру, изначально в селектах не прописан onChange="selectChanges(this, value);"? Они все генерятся одним скриптом. Собственно моя проблема в том, что необходимо три селекта исключить из такой способности, как сохранение выбора. В данном случае, если я правильно понял, сохраняются те селекты, где прописан onChange="selectChanges(this, value);", верно?

Comment: @Денис Добавил код с меткой `// дальше код проверки - нужно ли сохранять`